# Comprobar existencias de un producto de inventario con Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tengo listo un pequeño sistema de inventario el cual me funciona perfectamente, sin embargo, no he logrado conseguir que compruebe la disponibilidad de un producto a la hora de realizar una venta, si bien por un lado esta el comprobar si hay existencias, y por otro comprobar que la cantidad de venta se ajuste a la cantidad de existencias disponibles, creo que me doy a entender, creo que esto se podria lograr con ajax aunque no tengo en si bien una idea clara o una validación con condiciones, agradeceria puedan darme una mano, mi codigo es el siguiente:

**Migracion de la tabla Productos**

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name
      t.float :price
      t.integer :weight
      t.string :unity
      t.float :utility

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Migración de la tabla Transacciones del inventario**

```
class CreateInventoryTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :inventory_transactions do |t|
      t.string :invoice
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :provider
      t.integer :quantity
      t.boolean :transaction_type

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Modelo de Productos**

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord

    validates :code, :name, :price, :utility, :weight, :unity, presence: true
    validates :code, uniqueness: true

    has_many :inventory_transactions

    def quantity
        self.inventory_transactions.where(transaction_type: false).pluck(:quantity).sum - self.inventory_transactions.where(transaction_type: true).pluck(:quantity).sum
    end    

    def subtotal
        self.price * quantity
    end

    def profit
        subtotal * self.utility / 100
    end

    def iva
        (subtotal + profit) * 0.13
    end

    def total
        subtotal + profit + iva
    end

end
```

**Modelo de InventoryTransaction**

```
class InventoryTransaction < ApplicationRecord

    belongs_to :product

    def ganancia
        self.inventory_transactions.pluck(:utility)
    end 

end
```

**Formulario de Compra/Venta**

```
<%= form_with(model: inventory_transaction, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if inventory_transaction.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(inventory_transaction.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this inventory_transaction from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% inventory_transaction.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :factura %>
    <%= form.text_field :invoice %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :proveedor %>
    <%= form.text_field :provider %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :id_del_product %>
    <%= form.number_field :product_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :quantity %>
    <%= form.number_field :quantity %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :transaction_type %> <!-- Determina el tipo de transaccion en el inventario -->
    <%= form.select(:transaction_type, [['Compra', false], ['Venta', true]], { :include_blank => "Tipo de transacción" }, required: true, class: "input-group-field") %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

En conclusión, desde el formulario de transacciones, al realizar una transaccion de tipo venta, debe de comprobar en existencias, es decir por medio del metodo **quantity** que se encuentra en el modelo **Product**, debe de determinar si la cantidad de venta no es mayor a la disponibilidad de existencias en inventario, agradezco enormemente su ayuda, saludos!

Comment: ¿Exactamente en qué momento quieres llevar a cabo la validación?, ¿cuándo el usuario de clic en `submit`? ¿Por qué quisieras utilizar _AJAX_? Podrías enviar tu formulario y en tu controlador hacer la validación de inventario.

Comment: Exactamente Gerry, al hacer clic en submit, en caso la cantidad de pedido supere la cantidad de existencias, devuelva un mensaje diciendo que la cantidad de pedido supera la cantidad de existencias

Answer (score 0):

Una forma para lograrlo es agregando un método en tu modelo `InventoryTransaction` y utilizarlo a través de una validación; por ejemplo:

```
# app/models/inventory_transaction.rb

class InventoryTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  validate :product_quantity_available

  def ganancia
    self.inventory_transactions.pluck(:utility)
  end

  private
  def product_quantity_available
    if quantity > product.quantity
      errors.add(:base, 'Quantity not available')
    end
  end
end
```

En resumen, estas validando en tu modelo que la cantidad sea la correcta antes de guardarlo, tal como lo harías con cualquier otro atributo; la diferencia es que el valor de comparación se obtiene de otro modelo (para eso utilizamos `product.quantity`).

Ahora, al ser una validación más de tu modelo, el error<sup>1</sup> `'Quantity not available'` se mostrará en tu vista si la cantidad es mayor a la que tienes.

<sup><sup>1</sup> *`:base` permite agregar un mensaje de error sin la necesidad de asignarlo a un atributo del modelo.*</sup>

Comment: @HectorHernandez Como ejercicio (y mejora en la experiencia de usuario) podrías mostrar la cantidad disponible para el producto directamente en el formulario, lo cual podrías lograr utilizando _AJAX_ y el `product_id` que ingrese el usuario (ojo, esto no sustituye la validación en tu modelo).